# Combining two nested lists as one nested list

Tags: haskell

I want to combine two lists of lists and get a new nested list,Here is my code:

```
getAllPaths ::(Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [[a]]
getAllPaths [] = [[]]
getAllPaths (x:xs) = findAllPath (fst x) xs ++ getAllPaths xs
```

I want to combine the nested list returned from the findAllPath with all the elements from the recursive calls which are also nested list.

I know that `++` is used for combining two lists and no nested list but i also can't use first concat and then `++` because then list will be flatten.

Here is the type signature of `findAllPath`  and function also:

```
   findAllPath ::(Eq a) => a -> [(a,a)] -> [[a]]
   findAllPath val list = path val list
            where
                (first,second) = partition((==val).fst) list
                singl = map snd first
                path val list
                            | first == [] = [[val]]
                            | otherwise = map ((:) val) $ concat $ map (\x -> findAllPath x list) singl
```

This functionr returns all the possible paths from one node. I want to collect all the possible paths from all nodes.

For example, there are few paths from node 1 and 2 like this:

from node `1` to `[[1,2,3],[1,4,6]]`

from node `2` to  `[[2,7,9],[2,0,6]]]`

and i want a combination of `[[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,7,9],[2,0,6]]`

Can someone tell me how do it combine them in recursive call?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Do you want to concatenate "*rowwise*"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have added more information

Comment: Based on the information, I think `++` works fine. `(++)` appends two lists with the same type of data. The fact that that type is a list, does not changes anything. You probably want to change the basecase to `getAllPaths [] = []`.

Comment: No i get wrong result because `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` but i have here `[[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]` and i can't flatten anylist otherwise all the paths will be mixed. If i change Base-case then i can only return one list not a nested list

Comment: mind that the `a` of the signature of `(++)` is a different one than the `a` in `getAllPaths`. `(++)` has signature `[b] -> [b] -> [b]` if we disambiguate, and then `b ~ [a]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [WillemVanOnsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) mentions in the comments, you're looking for `(++)`. It may not be immediately obvious from the type signature but consider:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
-- if a ~ [b] then the specific type is:
(++) :: [[b]] -> [[b]] -> [[b]]
```

And by experiment:

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> [[1,2,3],[1,4,6]] ++ [[2,7,9],[2,0,6]]
[[1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,7,9],[2,0,6]]
```

If you have a whole list of these, you can combine with `foldr`.

```
foldr (++) [] (results :: [[[a]]])
```

or indeed `concat`

```
concat (results :: [[[a]]])
```

Comment: Pedantic note: `a :: [b]` is a (logical) type error: `a :: [b]` would mean that `a` is a *value* of type `[b]`. `~` is commonly used for type-level equality, so `a ~ [b]`.